# Is there reasons why innerhtml won't write

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a page with

```
<div id='new-feed-1367862865'>original</div>
```

I have an iframe with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var output-feed="<div id='new-feed-1367862872'></div>New"; 
  parent.document.getElementById('new-feed-1367862865').innerHTML=output-feed;
  </script>
```

Is there any reason why this won't change the content of the parent DIV. It's not working as much as I have tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`output-feed` is not a valid variable name. Use `output_feed` or `outputFeed` or something.

Comment: Wow, thanks.. let me change it and try again

Comment: It works, thanks! The problem as you spotted is in the - character used in the variable name

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I clicked on the Tick, but I was told that I can accept answers only in 3 mins... Is it?

Comment: @Ekene There is a [15-min limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this works
Working example http://jsfiddle.net/Js7uy/

```
<div id='new-feed-1367862865'>original</div>


  var output_feed="<div id='new-feed-1367862872'></div>New"; 
  document.getElementById('new-feed-1367862865').innerHTML=output_feed;
```

Key changes 
1. parent.document to document
2. output-feed to output_feed

Comment: The js is in an iframe, so the parent is useful, I guess

Answer (score 0):

use output_feed (underscore) to define output-feed instead of hyphen

Comment: forgot to ask, you realize that the result is a div inside a div and not a new div <div id='new-feed-1367862865'><div id='new-feed-1367862872'></div></div>, right?

Comment: Yes, I'd worry about that later with prepend()